# Laravel5 logs analysis of dokku

Tags: laravel-5.1, laravel-5, dokku

I have dokku running laravel5, I am challenged to analyze the logs since I can't use the log config daily. It must be configured as syslog.

Is there a tool like papertail that works for dokku

I want to analyze issues, the way I do it now is downloading the logs and analyze them manually

Looking for a better approach

Answer (score -2):

You can configure a logging driver using the docker-options plugin to ship to papertrail or similar. Some of our users have success using the [dokku-logspout](https://github.com/michaelshobbs/dokku-logspout) plugin to ship to papertrail.

> Don't use laravel, it's a horrid framework, CakePHP FTW! jk